# Using multidimensional array in Ada

Tags: ada

In this code, I need help writing a multidimensional array with a range between 2020-01-01 to 2119-12-31.
My code works but as you see there are no arrays in it. How can I write this code with only arrays?

```
with Ada.Text_IO;                    use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;            use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

Procedure Date is
type date_type is record
Str    : string (1..8);
Length : Natural := 0; end record;
A: date_type; 
begin
loop
Put ("Enter a date between 2020-01-01 to 2119-12-31 : "); 
Get_Line (A.Str, A.Length);
exit when A.Length = 8;
Put_Line ("Wrong input. Try again.");
end loop;
Put_Line (A.Str (1 .. 4) & "-" & A.Str (5 .. 6) & "-" & A.Str (7 .. 8));
end Date;
```

Comment: Ada array index values must be a discrete type such as an integer type or an enumeration type. They cannot be a string. Look at Ada Language Reference Manual sections 9.6 and 9.6.1 for conversion between strings, time, and day_count.

Comment: What do you want to do with your array? Why must it be a multidimensional array?

Comment: Arrays give the code a better structure and it would be easier to handle it

Comment: Since using an array is causing you trouble (why? what’s the problem?), it’s clearly _not_ "easier to handle". And, using an inappropriate language feature _doesn’t_ "give the code a better structure". I repeat Jim’s question, **what do you want to do with your array?**

Comment: Oh, and `2020-11-04` is 9 characters long, not 8

Comment: It's 8 characters if it's written in format yyyyddmm. So using arrays is not a good idea?

Comment: Your example dates in the prompt to the user include the hyphens! So the user is going to include the hyphens! Have you even _tried_ to run the code you posted? (BTW, I see that the ISO-format date is actually 10 characters, not 9 - my bad).

Comment: We know that a string is an array of characters. I don’t think any of us can understand why you’d think that an array (of what?) would be a good approach to handling dates. And why multidimensional? what would be the indices?

Comment: Perhaps an array indexed by `(Year_Number, Month_Number, Day_Number) of Boolean` to indicate if the date is valid?

Comment: Yes, only just over 2^15 elements so not unreasonable. Personally I’d look at an ordered map Date -> Boolean. But it does depend on the intended use.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, rather than a multi-dimensional array you should consider using a record such as

```
type Year_Number  is range 1900..3000;
type Month_Number is range 1..12;
type Day_Number   is range 1..31;

type Date_Rec is record
   Year  : Year_Number;
   Month : Month_Number;
   Day   : Day_Number;
end record;

subtype Year_String  is string (1..4);
subtype Month_String is string (1..2);
subtype Day_String   is string (1..2);

function To_Date (Yr : Year_String; Mnth : Month_String; Dy : Day_String) 
                  return Date_Rec is
   Result : Date_Rec;
begin
   Result.Year  := Year_Number'Value (Yr);
   Result.Month := Month_Number'Value (Mnth);
   Result.Day   := Day_Number'Value (Dy);
   return Result;
end To_Date;
```

You can now pass around instances of Date_
Rec doing whatever you want with the date.
If you go this far then you might want to consider using the Time type described in Ada Language Reference Manual sections 9.6 and 9.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't asked a reasonable question here because `"I want to use arrays"` is not a good reason to use an array.

`"This problem can be best solved with an array ... but how do I deal with ... ?"` would be a reasonable question, but you haven't stated a problem,let alone one that needs an array.

This is important because "using an array" is thinking in the solution domain, like "using a chisel". It's not the way to think about programming in Ada, (or IMO in any language).

Try thinking in the problem domain first : instead of "I want to use a chisel", I think "I want to recess this hinge so the door fits precisely" and a chisel is the neatest way of doing the job.

Then `"How can I best validate a date?"` would be one reasonable question, or `"how can I store events that happen on each day for 100 years?"`

The answer to the first question is probably in the `Ada.Calendar` package. Possibly the `Value` function in `Ada.Calendar.Formatting`, with an exception handler to catch incomprehensible strings and make the user try again.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;       use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Calendar;
with Ada.Calendar.Formatting;

procedure date is
 Date : Ada.Calendar.Time;
 Done : Boolean;
begin

  loop
    Put ("Enter a date between 2020-01-01 to 2119-12-31 : "); 
    Done := TRUE;
    declare
      A : String := Get_Line & " 12:00:00";
    begin
      Date := Ada.Calendar.Formatting.Value(A);   -- validate it's a date
      Done := Ada.Calendar.Year(Date) >= 2020 
              and Ada.Calendar.Year(Date) < 2120; -- validate correct range
    exception  
      when Constraint_Error => Done := False;     -- Formatting.Value failed
    end;
    exit when Done;
    Put("Try Again : ");
  end loop;

end date;
```

The answer to the second is probably a 1-dimensional array indexed by `Day_Count` from `Ada.Calendar.Arithmetic` but let's use the wrong tool : a 3D array indexed by your range of years, `Month_Number` and `Day_Number` from the `Ada.Calendar` base package.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;       use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Calendar;      use Ada.Calendar;
with Ada.Calendar.Formatting;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

procedure date is
 Date : Ada.Calendar.Time;
 Done : Boolean := TRUE;
 
 Event_Array : array(2020 .. 2119, 
                     Ada.Calendar.Month_Number, 
                     Ada.Calendar.Day_Number) of Unbounded_String;
begin

  Event_Array := (others => (others => (others => Null_Unbounded_String)));
  Event_Array(2020,11,3) := To_Unbounded_String("nothing much");
  loop
    Put ("Enter a date between 2020-01-01 to 2119-12-31 : "); 
    Done := TRUE;
    declare
      A : String := Get_Line & " 12:00:00";
    begin
      Date := Ada.Calendar.Formatting.Value(A);
      Done := Ada.Calendar.Year(Date) >= 2020 
              and Ada.Calendar.Year(Date) < 2120;
    exception  
      when Constraint_Error => Done := False;
    end;
    exit when Done;
    Put("Try Again : ");
  end loop;
  Put_Line("Today " & Ada.Calendar.Formatting.Image(Date) & " : " &
             To_String(Event_Array(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date))) & " happened");
  
end date;
```

Test with the string `2020-11-03`